# Reference a static value based on a sum of a column

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to reference one singular number that is the sum of a column in a table. In the example below, I want to be able to reference the total of 10 and use that in another measure to create percentages and the 10 (or that new measure) not change based on any factor.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
My measure = 
  CALCULATE(
    SUM('myTable'[column]),
    ALL('myTable')
  )
```